# Shell script for getting the sequence and changing it?

Tags: unix, shell, sed, awk

I have a command like

```
echo "abcd0001gfh.DAT" | sed 's/^[^0-9]*\(....\).*$/\1/' | awk '{ print "00"$0 }'
```

This will give me an output of 000001. But I want to run 
this in a loop where I receive the file name from 0001-9999 
and again it becomes 0001. So my output should like below

```
abcd0001gfh.DAT 000001
abcd0002gfh.DAT 000002
.
.
.
abcd9999gfh.DAT 009999
abcd0001gfh.DAT 010001
.
.
abcd9999gfh.DAT 019999
abcd0001gfh.DAT 020001
```

There is also a chance that I will receive 0005 after 0002
and here I consider 0003 and 0004 as missing sequences.

I want a limit to be set so the value of the prefix
ranges from 00-99 i.e., the value can go up to 999999. So the
loop should go until 9999 is received 99 times in the
input file.

How could this be done in a shell script?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have your .DAT filenames stored in a file called `datfiles.list`. What you want is to increment the prefix every time the new extracted value is smaller than the previous.

```
lastSeq=0;
prefix=0;
for name in `cat datfiles.list`; do 
    seq=`echo $name | sed 's/^[^0-9]*\(....\).*$/\1/' | awk '{ print "00"$0 }'`
    if [[ $seq < $lastSeq ]]; then
        prefix=$(($prefix+1));
    fi
    lastSeq=$seq;
    printf "%02d%06d\n" $prefix $seq
done;
```

This seems to produce the output you want. Note the use of printf at the end to zero-pad the fields.

Comment: Yes Peter...my .DAT filenames stored in a file called datfiles.list.but the problem over here is i keep receiving the files one after other sequentially and at some instances some sequences can also miss.so the script shoudl keep on polling the directory and give the sequence accordingly.so i think this solution ..even though its good but does solve the purpose.

Comment: Do you mean that the script should wait for a file in the sequence if it is missing?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this script helps a little. But there is still a problem with the missing files and the order in which they arrive. What if there will be no ????9999.DAT file? `$sequence` will not increment. What if ????9998.DAT arrives after ????9999.DAT? `$sequence` will be already be incremented. But, perhaps you will find a solution for that. Last but not least, in case you will use the code, you need something to update the `.ts` file when you break the loop. You could also move the computed files to a different directory.

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

datadir=/home/cheko/tmp/test/datloop/data
ts=$datadir/.ts
latest=$datadir/.ts
timeout=20

if [ -f $ts ]
then
    sequence=`cat $ts`
else
    sequence=0
    echo $sequence > $ts
    touch -t 197001011212 $ts
fi

while true
do
    for file in `find $datadir -type f -newer $latest`
    do
        file=`basename $file`
        number=`echo $file | sed -n 's/^.*\([0-9]\{4,4\}\)\.DAT/\1/p'`
        echo $number
        printf "%-20s %02d%s\n" $file $sequence $number
        if [ "$number" = "9999" ]
        then
            sequence=$((sequence+1))
            echo $sequence > $ts
        fi
    done
    latest=$datadir/$file
    sleep $timeout
done
```